# Laravel Datatables display data from related tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Datatables for displaying data. It works good, but when I want to display data from related tables (models), they do not appear.
**Model Keyword.php**

```
public function website() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Website');
}
```

**Model Website.php**

```
 public function keywords() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Keyword');
}
```

**'websites' database table**: id, siteName, siteUrl
**'keywords' database table**: id, website_id, kwName

Url that should display data: **projects/'.$website->id.'/edit** (example: projects/2/edit - (edit is a blade))
So, at this Url I want to show a datatable that display all kwName for certain website_id(in this example /2/).

Please, help me what should I use and how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your Eloquent relationships are the wrong way around.

`keywords` has a reference to `website` via `website_id`, this is a **belongsTo relationship**.

`website` is referenced by many `keywords`, so this is a **hasMany relationship**.

[Laravel 5.4 Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: just to comment: you can make them point to eachother no problem e.g. `$farmer->hasmany('chicken')` and `$chicken->hasone('farmer')`

Comment: No, that won't work. In a good database design there's always a hasOne/hasMany, and a belongsTo/belongsToMany relation. What you're saying is that a chicken `hasOne` farmer (farmer keeps record of that 1 chicken, while also keeping record of 'many' other chickens via chicken.farmer_id).

Comment: yeah about that you are right, that was a typo. correction: it should be `$chicken->belongsto('farmer')`. good spot!

Comment: A website may have many keywords (website->hasMany('App\Keyword')
A keyword (identical) can be found in many websites(keywords->belongsToMany('App\Website'). So, I think it is possible.